# Etimologia di "biocca"

Tags: etymology

Cercado di tracciare l'etimologia di "abbiocco", così, per curiosità, ho trovato [1](https://unaparolaalgiorno.it/significato/A/abbiocco) e [2](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/lessico/lessico_104.html), che lo riconducono a *biocca*, equivalente di *chioccia*.

Una ricerca Google dell'etimologia di quest'ultima parola, che suppongo sia una voce regionale (come è *abbiocco*, d'altronde), non ha portato a nulla.

Tirando a indovinare, potrei supporre che *chioccia* si sia in qualche modo evoluto in *biocca* in qualche regione, anche se questo mi sembra alquanto strano. Anche accettando questa ipotesi, posso risalire a *chiocciare*, ma il [Wikizionario](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chioccia) qua mi dà soltanto "possibly from latin *glocire*", e non si risale più indietro. Anzi, a dir la verità dice che potrebbe essere avvenuto il contrario, cioè da *chioccia* sia venuto *chiocciare*. [etimo.it](http://etimo.it/?cmd=id&id=3600&md=4cbefa4339a5d2a2aed447be08f49f1a) mi dà un sacco di parole "imparentate" con *chiocciare*, tra cui *cluck* in Inglese, da cui col [Wikizionario](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cluck) risalgo al Proto-Germanico *klukkwōną*, parola onomatopeica. Quindi in definitiva avrei la seguente etimologia:

```
abbiocco<biocca<(?)chioccia<(?)chiocciare<??<klukkwōną
```

Quindi restano tre domande:

1. È vero che *biocca* viene da *chioccia* o viene da un'altra parte?
2. È *chioccia* che viene da *chiocciare* o viceversa?
3. Come si sono generate le parole *chioccia* e *chiocciare*, e risalgono davvero a *klukkwōną* o sono a sé stanti? E il Latino *glocire*, *glociare*, *glocitare* come entra in questa faccenda?

Comment: ***Biocca***: (voce contadinesca), si appella così la gallina quando cova le uova e alleva i pulcini. http://dizionario.org/d/?pageurl=biocca

Comment: ***Abbioccàre***: 
[comp. di a- (2) e ***del roman. biocca ‘chioccia’*** ☼ 1846] - http://dizionaripiu.zanichelli.it/parola-del-giorno/2012/03/02/abbioccare__abbioccato__abbiocco/

Comment: ***Chioccia***: s. f. *[der. di chiocciare]* - ***Chiocciare***  v. intr. [voce onomatopeica; cfr. il ***lat. glocire e il gr. κλώζω]***  1. Riferito alle galline, emettere il verso caratteristico del periodo in cui sono chiocce. http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ricerca/chioccia/

Comment: ***Chioccia***: estratto da chiocciare, incrocio del latino glocio (inf. glocire "chiocciare", ***di origine onomatopeica, cnfr. il greco klozein) e del tardo latino clocca "campana"***, parola di origine celtica. https://it.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/chioccio

Comment: Abbiocco sta per sensazione di sonno, pesantezza e stanchezza

Comment: Non è questo che si chiedeva, @Emanuel.

Comment: Sul GDLI per [biocca](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI02/GDLI_02_ocr_244.pdf&parola=biocca) si trova sf. Dial. Chioccia = etimo incerto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Biocca* è una parola romanesca che significa *chioccia*:

> La chioccia, biocca in Roma, la gallina c'ha i pulcini;
>
> - [*Lexicon Tetraglotton, an English-French-Italian-Spanish Dictionary*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PCtWAAAAYAAJ&pg=PP519&dq="biocca"+"chioccia") (1660)

È una delle molte varianti regionali, che si ipotizza (come dici tu) derivi dal latino *gloccire* (o come una deformazione di *chioccia*, o un discendente parallelo in un'altra lingua romanza):

> Vròcca, Vlòcca, Blocca, Biocca, Locca, chioccia == Cfr. lat *Glocùns. Gloccire* — *Nel dial. di Scanno, spiedo. Fr. *Brache*. Cfr. con l'ital. Brocco, Sbrocco.
>
> - [*Vocabolario dell'uso abbruzese*](https://archive.org/details/vocabolariodell00finagoog/page/n228), 1880

> **ab·bioc·cà·re** *v tr e intr* (reg biocca, chioccia, +ad+āre; 1859), ing ... fr ...  sp... ted proprio della chioccia che cova le uova, estens assopire, <sub>**abbioccarsi** rifl, assopirsi</sub>
>
> - [DIZIONARIO EUROPEO (ITALIANO)](https://docplayer.it/30847603-Dizionario-europeo-italiano.html)

Comment: Molte grazie per la risposta e il lavoro che ci hai messo. L'ultimo testo, però, quello sul dialetto narnese, era già stato citato in un'altra risposta e già lì avevo segnalato il mio scetticismo circa l'attendibilità di una fonte amatoriale che inventa un nesso etimologico con “bios”...

Comment: @DaG ah scusa, rimuoverò quella citazione.

Comment: Immagino che "lingua romantica" fosse in realtà una "lingua romanza" (ho fatto la correzione).

Comment: @Charo sì, grazie!

Answer (score 0):

Credo che qui, a pagina 27, puoi trovare una soluzione per "biocca".
http://www.lamemoriadinarni.it/doc/2016_05/ALL_1_20160526_230657_1_620.pdf

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE! "Link only posts" non sono considerati come vere risposte. Potresti aggiungere qualche dettaglio su quello che sta chiedendo l'OP?

Comment: Personalmente, a un'opera di consultazione amatoriale che conclude una voce con “ed, inoltre, il formulare l’ipotesi di una etimologia dal gr. bios = vita, è azzardato?” rispondo “sì”, la chiudo e cerco altrove.

Comment: Non era quello il punto. L'etimologia di "biocca" da "bios" non ha alcun senso, ma le citazioni di numerose forme meridionali in vl- col medesimo significato portano a concludere che il bi- potesse derivare da un *bl- (*blocca), variante di *vl-.
Un verbo *vloccare potrebbe essere benissimo alla base delle forme in *vl- e derivare da un tardo latino *voculare>*voclare>*vlocare>*vloccare.